# How to make a condition that the number of a letter in the ASCII table is equal a range of numbers in C?

Tags: c, ascii

I want to check if the string has only capital letters, but I would like to know if it is possible to check if a letter in the string is equal to a range of numbers in the ASCII table. this is what I wrote until now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    int length, x = 0, counter = 0;
    printf("Enter your password length: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    char password[length];
    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", &password);
}
```

I don't know how to continue from there.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Use [isupper()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper)?

Comment: Firstly fix your code: 1. `void main()` is non-standard. It should be `int main(void)` unless you have special reason to use `void` (like your teacher or boss doesn't allow `int`). 2. You have to allocate at least `length+1` elements to store `length`-character string because there must be a terminate null-character at the end of string. 3. Most arrays in expressions are automatically converted to pointers. You should use `password`, not `&password`, for `scanf()`.

Comment: 1. I prefer to use `void` cause I didn't learn to use `int`.
2. On other exercises I did it like that and everything was OK.
3. I did like that on other exercises and it worked.

Comment: I don't want to use `isupper()` because I want to know better the ASCII table and I want to practice that, but thanks for letting me know about this function!

Comment: @Daniel if everything looks OK that doesn't mean that it _is_ actually OK. If you come to this site, take the opportunity and learn what people tell you.

Comment: If you don't want to use `isupper()` and practice that's fine. The you need to write your own version  of `isupper()` which is pretty simple, it's actually one line of code.

Comment: I know that it is pretty simple and I know that it is only 1 line of code, but I don't know how to do that. Can you explain me, please?

Comment: `int is_uppercase(char something) { return something >= 'A' && something <= 'Z' }` - you can extend this for the whole `char* word` parameter you'll need.

Comment: @Daniel: 1. You learned to use `int` just now. C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 says `main` “shall be defined with a return type of `int`…” It does allow implementation-defined forms, but those should be used only with good cause, and having a teacher who did not teach you correctly is not a good cause.

Comment: @Daniel: 2. Re “2. On other exercises I did it like that and everything was OK.” That is not a justification. When you use memory beyond the defined limit of an array, you use memory not reserved for that purpose. It can appear “OK” in the same way that going into a house that you do not belong in might be “OK” because nobody catches you, but it is no evidence you will not be caught and punished the next time you try it.

Comment: @Daniel: 3. This is the same as 2. Passing `&password`, a pointer to an array, to `scanf` to receive a string of characters, is an error. The fact it did not have bad consequences this time is not evidence it will not fail in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the string from the user, all you need to do is iterating the string you created and checking if the char at that index is between 65 and 90.

[ascii table](https://bournetocode.com/projects/GCSE_Computing_Fundamentals/pages/img/ascii_table_lge.png)

Comment: Use 'A' and 'Z' instead of 65/90 - Makes the code more readable

Comment: I said so because there was "range of numbers" in question. What you are saying is better imo too.